Maximum number of leaves in a tree with maximum degree 3 and a perfect matching.
I'm trying to solve a graph theory problem that states

Let $n\geq2$ be an integer. What is the maximum possible number of leaves in a tree $T$ such that $|V(T)|=2n$, $\Delta(G)\leq 3$ and $T$ has a perfect matching (as a function of n)?

Firstly, I attempted using the fact that $T$ would have no $K_3$ subgraph, so $|E(G)|\leq 2|V(G)|-4$, but that led me nowhere. Next, I tried using the handshaking lemma and the fact that $T$ has maximum degree 3 to say that if $L$ is the set of leaves of $T$, then
$$2|E(G)|=\sum_{v\in V(G)} \deg(v) = \sum_{v\in L}\deg (v)+\sum_{v\notin L}\deg(v)\leq |L|+3|V(G)-L|$$
and then using the fact that $|E(G)|=|V(G)|-1=2n-1$ to say that
$|L|\leq \lfloor\frac{|V(G)|+2}{2}\rfloor=n+1$.
But this isn't really convincing because I didn't use the fact that there is a perfect matching. I'm not sure how to do this though, so any help would be appreciated!

Let $T$ be a tree on $2n$ vertices, and let $T$ have a perfect matching. Note that if $n=1$, the unique tree on two vertices has two leaves and a perfect matching. For $n\geq 2$, we show that $T$ has at most $n$ leaves, and this bound is tight.
Since $T$ has a perfect matching $M$, every leaf $l$ in $T$ is matched to its unique neighbour $N(l)$ in $M$. $N(l)$ is not a leaf, unless $n=1$. Thus, there are at least as many non-leaf vertices in $T$ as there are leaves, so the number of leaves in $T$ is at most $n$.
We now give an example of a tree on $2n$ vertices with $n$ leaves. Let $P_n$ be the path on $n$ vertices, and let $T_n$ be obtained from $P_n$ by adding a leaf adjacent to every vertex of $P_n$. Then $T_n$ has a perfect matching, $\Delta(T_n)\leq 3$, and $|V(T_n)|=2n$.
Note that the assumption that our tree must have maximum degree $3$ is not constraining. Furthermore, the above example is the unique tree on $2n$ vertices with $n$ leaves.
